# Why is python adding different space lengths when using tab?

Tags: python, tabs, indentation

Why do I get different amounts of spaceing between each \t and how would I go about fixing this?

```
print ("\tName1:\tName2:\tNumber1:\tNumber2:")
```

Output:

```
Name1:  Name2:  Number1:    Number2:
```

The space between Number1: and Number2: is not the same as the first two; how would I go about fixing this?

Comment: if you want fixed spacing, use spaces. tab most likely considers the length of the string between the tabs, i.e. try `print ("\tName1:\tName2:\tName3:\tName4:")` and see what happens

Comment: @ryugie I see, using the same string length between each tab gives me the same amount of spacing

Answer (score 1):

The console has tab-stops at every 8 spaces.  If you are passed a tab-stop, it moves to the next one.  You can see where the tab-stops are here:

```
print("\tName1:\tName2:\tNumber1:\tNumber2:") 
print('1234567890'*5)
print('\t^'*5)
        Name1:  Name2:  Number1:        Number2:
123456781234567812345678123456781234567812345678
        ^       ^       ^       ^       ^
```

It makes sure that at least 1 space still exists after a tab.  That is why `Number2:` got moved to the next tab-stop.

If you want to print with a pre-fixed spacing, you can do it like this:

```
header = ['Name1:', 'Name2:', 'Number1:', 'Number2:']
# set the width of the headers as the widest string length plus 4
width = max(len(h) for h in header) + 4
print('{: <w}{: <w}{: <w}{: <w}'.replace('w',str(width)).format(*header))

# output:
Name1:      Name2:      Number1:    Number2:
```

The print statement is a bit confusing, but it sets the number of spaces to pad each string with as `width`.

Answer (score 0):

\t advances to the next tab stop; this is usually set to the next multiple of 8 columns.  In other words, it's not broken: it's working just as it's supposed to.

If you want the same quantity of spaces between your labels, then use a fixed number of spaces, rather than tabs.  For instance:

```
space = "    "
print "Name1" + space +
      "Name2" + space +
      "Name3" + space +
      "Name4"
```

You can also use [formatted output](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_formatted_output.php).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to put `n` spaces between each string.

```
>>> n = 3
>>> print((' '*n).join(('Name1:', 'Name2:', 'Number1:', 'Number2:')))
Name1:   Name2:   Number1:   Number2:
```